# window.close() generates an issue

Tags: javascript, window

this code generates problem [encountered problem of window] and close all the safari windows, 
but this code is working fine with Internet Explorer. What will I do ?
have any alternative method for closing current opened window in every browser.

```
<input type='button' value='close' onclick='window.close()'>
```

Comment: `window.close` will not normally have that effect. I'd look for script in the window that binds to the `unload` or `beforeunload` events and see if there's something else there that might be causing it, because those events will get triggered when you close the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that sounds pretty weird, this isn't documented behavior.

Mozilla Gecko DOM reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close

MSDN Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536367(VS.85).aspx

Safari Reference documentation [Domwindow.close()](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/WebKitDOMRef/DOMWindow_idl/Classes/DOMWindow/index.html#//apple_ref/js/instm/DOMWindow/close/void/()) - you'll find, err, nothing.

Comment: Thanks for these links, that are use ful for me